# Why doesn't my computer see a Wifi that my phone does?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, essid

I have access to several Wifi networks from my place and even though I can often connect to the one I need for printing purposes, that's not always the case, because my system (Ubuntu 16.04) doesn't see it and says it's out of range, even though my phone, which is next to the computer, does see the network and is connected to it.
I've tried to restart the network-manager and the networking service, but that doesn't do anything.
It has to be a problem of my system, since it's the one that doesn't see that network.
What could be the reason of this?

Edit:

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is as follows

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [185f:051a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] [11ab:4381] (rev 11)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Probably, your phone has a better antenna built in or the deflexion of the radio waves is lower thanks to the better position of an antenna, a better case, or a smaller electromagnetic interference from the components on the phone's circuitry. I have a similar issue. My old netbook (`Acer AOD260`)  sees more access points than the newer computers. Some networks also can be broadcasted through the frequencies inaccessible for the receiver (2,4 GHz antenna cannot search for 5,0 GHz broadcast, and *vice versa*).

Comment: Christianus, that doesn't explain my problem because I'm always at the same place and I can sometimes (or even frequently) see the network and connect to it without problems and with a good signal.

Comment: Can your phone tell you what channel the one wifi AP is on?  I would bet it is higher than channel 11 on 2.4Ghz

Comment: I can sometimes receive a radio station with a perfect sound, sometimes the same station has a very bad reception. The electromagnetic field created by the transmitter undergo superficial alterations (coverage of the area changes). What a network adapter (WiFi card) do you have inside the cell *vis-à-vis* WiFi card of a computer? Determine the difference in physical properties of connections: 1) frequency (range), 2)  channel of the radio operation (as @Jeremy31 put). Then make comparison trying to force devices to use the same channel on the same band.

Comment: My new Dlink DIR-891 router provides two interfaces, 1 "normal" and the other "5G". My phone can see both, but my old laptop's WiFi NIC doesn't support 5G, so it only sees the "normal" one. Could this be your problem?

Comment: I can't remember ever seeing a broadcom wifi card work in Linux on 2.4Ghz on a channel higher than 11